# Placeholder text problem in Area 51 comments during commitment

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I'm seeing many "Why are you supporting this site, and how will you contribute to it?" comments on Area 51 commits. These are just a couple of examples:

From the [Pro Webmasters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) proposal:

[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/2940/area51why.jpg](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/2940/area51why.jpg)

From the [Statistical Analysis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33/statistical-analysis) proposal:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8876/awhyareyou.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8876/awhyareyou.jpg)

It looks like sometimes the placeholder text breaks:

[alt text http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9437/commentsqs.jpg](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9437/commentsqs.jpg)

Comment: I saw one of those in Gaming and I figured that person was just playing around... but the presence elsewhere speaks otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why our client-side check wasn't catching this, but I've nevertheless added the check to the back end as well.

The 31 "Why are you supporting..." commitment comments that slipped through have been nulled out in the database.